# Iterar sobre relojes biometricos y replicar imagenes tomadas en cada reloj C# SDK Hikvision

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, asp

Actualmente estoy trabajando con el `SDK` de `Hikvision` implementado en una `aplicación WinForms` para la toma de fotografias faciales.

Tengo unos requerimientos por hacer que en su mayoria dos de ellos he podido completarlos. Pero hay uno que no he logrado aun implementarlo del todo, a su vez comprendido para poder hacerlo.

Tabla

```
EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaParam
Campos
       [IdParametro]              int           (debe ser 1, solo existirá un registro)
       [DireccionFotoEmpleado]    varchar      (dirección de carpeta donde guardara la imagen)
```

Realizar
Mantenimiento siempre, solo Modificar registro existente

Tabla

```
REP_ImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg
Campos
       [CodigoEmpleado]    [varchar]     código de empleado a quien se le tomo la foto
       [CreadoPor]         [varchar]     código de usuario que tomo la foto
       [FechaCreacion]     [datetime]    fecha/hora que se tomo la foto
       [Imagen]            [varchar]     nombre de la imagen guardada en la captura
```

Realizar En la captura de imagen de empleado,

- **Si no existe registro del empleado**:
  insertar registro con todos los datos
- **Si existe registro del empleado:** actualizar campos, CreadoPor, FechaCreacion, Imagen
  Borrar los registros de la tabla REP_DispositivoBiometricoFacialImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg con el código de empleado a quien se tomo la foto.

Tengo una función del `SDK`  llamada **ProcessCapFaceData** que se encarga de realizar la captura de la fotografia, es ahi donde mando a llamar el resto de funciones que he creado para poder implementar los primeros dos requerimientos.

```
  //Funcion que captura la imagen y la guarda en la carpeta.
   private void ProcessCapFaceData(ref CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_CAPTURE_FACE_CFG struFaceCfg, ref bool flag)
   {
       if (0 == struFaceCfg.dwFacePicSize)
       {
           return;
       }

       string codigoUsuario = textBoxCardNo.Text;  // Obtener el código del usuario desde el cuadro de texto
       //Declaramos variable para almacenar la informacion de la imagen
       string strUbicacionRuta = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\dsolares\Documents\Pruebas desarrollo\Evento Foto", $"{codigoUsuario}.jpg");

       try
       {
           using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(strUbicacionRuta, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
           {
               int faceLen = struFaceCfg.dwFacePicSize;
               byte[] by = new byte[faceLen];
               Marshal.Copy(struFaceCfg.pFacePicBuffer, by, 0, faceLen);
               fs.Write(by, 0, faceLen);
           }

           pictureBoxFace.Image = Image.FromFile(strUbicacionRuta);
           textBoxFilePath.Text = strUbicacionRuta;
           MessageBox.Show("Capture succeed", "SUCCESSFUL", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

           //Instanciamos la funcion para capturar la direccion de la imagen
           InsertarOActualizarDireccionFoto(strUbicacionRuta);

           //Instanciamos la funcion para capturar los datos en la tabla imagenEmpleadoRondaSeg
           capturarDatosDB(codigoUsuario, strUbicacionRuta);

       }
       catch
       {
           flag = false;
           MessageBox.Show("Capture data wrong", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
       }
   }
   private void InsertarOActualizarDireccionFoto(string direccionFoto)
   {
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conexion.CN))
       {
           connection.Open();

           // Verificar si ya existe un registro en la tabla
           string selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaParam WHERE IdParametro = 1";

           using (SqlCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection))
           {
               int count = Convert.ToInt32(selectCmd.ExecuteScalar());

               if (count > 0)
               {
                   // Si existe, actualizar la dirección de la foto
                   string updateQuery = "UPDATE EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaParam SET DireccionFotoEmpleado = @DireccionFotoEmpleado WHERE IdParametro = 1";

                   using (SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, connection))
                   {
                       updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DireccionFotoEmpleado", direccionFoto);
                       updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   // Si no existe, insertar un nuevo registro
                   string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaParam (IdParametro, DireccionFotoEmpleado) VALUES (1, @DireccionFotoEmpleado)";

                   using (SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection))
                   {
                       insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DireccionFotoEmpleado", direccionFoto);
                       insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   private void capturarDatosDB(string codigoUsuario, string ubicacionImagen)
   {
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conexion.CN))
       {
           connection.Open();

           bool existeUsuario = VerificarUsuarioExistDB(codigoUsuario);
           if (existeUsuario)
           {
               ActualizarRegistroEnREPImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg(codigoUsuario, ubicacionImagen);

           }
           else
           {
               InsertarNuevoRegistroEnREPImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg(codigoUsuario, ubicacionImagen);

           }
       }
   }
   private bool VerificarUsuarioExistDB(string codigoUsuario)
   {
       try
       {
           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conexion.CN))
           {
               connection.Open();

               string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REP_ImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg WHERE CodigoEmpleado = @CodigoEmpleado";

               using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
               {
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoEmpleado", codigoUsuario);

                 
                   int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                   return count > 0;
               }
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // Manejar la excepción, por ejemplo, logear el error
           Console.WriteLine($"Error en VerificarUsuarioExistDB: {ex.Message}");
           return false; 
       }
   }
   private void ActualizarRegistroEnREPImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg(string codigoUsuario, string ubicacionImagen)
   {
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conexion.CN))
       {
           connection.Open();


           string query = "UPDATE REP_ImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg SET Imagen = @Imagen WHERE CodigoEmpleado = @CodigoEmpleado";
           string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(ubicacionImagen);
           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoEmpleado", codigoUsuario);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", ubicacionImagen);

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
       }
   }
   private void InsertarNuevoRegistroEnREPImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg(string codigoUsuario, string ubicacionImagen)
   {
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conexion.CN))
       {
           connection.Open();

           string nombreArchivo = Path.GetFileName(ubicacionImagen);  // Obtener solo el nombre del archivo

           string query = "INSERT INTO REP_ImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg (CodigoEmpleado, CreadoPor, FechaCreacion, Imagen) VALUES (@CodigoEmpleado, @CreadoPor, @FechaCreacion, @Imagen)";

           using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
           {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoEmpleado", codigoUsuario);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreadoPor", "UsuarioActual"); // Ajustar esta linea segun la lógica para obtener el código de usuario actual
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaCreacion", DateTime.Now);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", nombreArchivo);

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           }
       }
   }
```

**ESTE ES EL TERCER REQUERIMIENTO QUE ES EL QUE NO TENGO IDEA DE COMO HACER UN PROCESO INDEPENDIENTE Y QUE ESTE AL MOMENTO DE REALIZAR LA CAPTURA UN RELOJ BIOMETRICO, REPLIQUE LA IMAGEN TOMADA EN CADA UNO DE LOS DISPOSITIVOS DISPONIBLES, LA TABLA EN DONDE ESTAN SE LLAMA EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg**

Table

```
REP_DispositivoBiometricoFacialImagenEmpleadoRondaSeg
Campos
       [IdDispositivo]     [uniqueidentifier]  código del reloj donde se ha replicado
       [CodigoEmpleado]    [varchar]           código del empleado replicado
       [CreadoPor]         [varchar]           usuario que actualizo (sistema)
       [FechaCreacion]     [datetime]          fecha hora de actualización
```

Realizar

Crear proceso independiente, que tomara las imágenes tomadas y las replicara en cada dispositivo existente en `EQ_DispositivoBiometricoRondaSeg`, que no tenga registro de actualización.

Se llenará el registro únicamente si actualizo el reloj con éxito la imagen.

Este deberá tener un `timer parametrizable` desde archivo de texto `xx.txt` que con el siguiente formato:

```
Servidor|Basededatos|usuariosql|clavesql|milisegundostimer
```

Ejemplo:

```
DB19|IT-GDY|USRDEV|LaClave|60000
```

Comment: Yo no entiendo cual es el problema que tenes.. ahi tenes un requerimiento, no un problema....

Comment: @gbianchi tienes alguna idea de como implementar ese requerimiento? hasta ahora capturo las imágenes y estas son guardadas de manera local. Pero ahora de que manera tomo esas imágenes utilizando quizá una aplicacion de consola, utilizándola como servicio de Windows de manera independiente y replicarlas en cada uno de los relojes biométricos que tengo disponibles y en mi tabla de la DB?

Comment: justamente como lo decis.. no entiendo el problema, si necesitas un analisis de tu sistema, no se si este seria el lugar adecuado, porque capaz todos tenemos visiones distintas de como hacerlo. Sigo sin ver un problema, un requerimiento no es un problema, es lo que tenes que hacer, pero no es un problema de programacion, es un problema de arquitectura que depende de muchas mas cosas de las que describis aca... si ya tenes la informacion, replicarla es algo "trivial" que podrias hacer como quieras...